# how to sort an NSArray using compare:options

Tags: iphone, sorting, compare, nsarray

I have an NSArray containing numbers as NSString objects. ie.

```
[array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 100]];
```

How do I sort the array numerically? Can I use `compare:options` and specify `NSNumericSearch` as `NSStringCompareOptions`? Please give me an example/sample code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the example code given for the [`sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:) method which should work fine for NSStrings too as they also have the `intValue` method.

```
// Place this functions somewhere above @implementation
static NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = [num1 intValue];
    int v2 = [num2 intValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}

// And used like this
NSArray *sortedArray; 
sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSort context:NULL];
```

Comment: +1 You can replace the body of intSort with just this line: return [(NSString*)num1 compare:num2 options:NSNumericSearch];

Comment: @gerry3 Sure, I just pulled the example code given at apple.com which looked like it would do the job

Answer (score 6):

Since your objects are numbers, instead of using NSString objects, you could use NSNumber objects (easily turned into strings via the stringValue property) and sort the array using [sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCJGCJI).

For example:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sorter, nil];
[sorter release];
NSArray *sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorters];
[sorters release];
```