# Sorted List Array Question

Tags: iphone, sqlite

On sorting an array i get : 1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. What went wrong ?

My code was:

```
        NSArray *sortedArray = [optionKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

where optionKeys were: 7,3,8,4,9,5,1,6,2,10

i had also tried CaseInsensitiveCompare: and got the same result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to let the sortedArrayUsingSelector using integer to sort instead of String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752992/how-to-let-the-sortedarrayusingselector-using-integer-to-sort-instead-of-string)

Answer (score 1):

String comparison will place 10 after 1. You'll need to use a number comparison function. This may help: [How to let the sortedarrayusingselector using integer to sort instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752992/how-to-let-the-sortedarrayusingselector-using-integer-to-sort-instead-of-string)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a string sort rather than a numeric sort.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752992/how-to-let-the-sortedarrayusingselector-using-integer-to-sort-instead-of-string).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031990/how-to-sort-an-nsarray-using-compareoptions). You want to do a numeric sort instead of a string sort.