# iOS compare intValue of NSString within an NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have a dico NSDictionary containing things like:
    {
    123 = ,
    125 = ,
    ...
    73  = 
    }

123, 125, .., 73 are NSString.

I'd like to have an NSArray containing the objects ordered by their id:

```
[ <MyObject:73>, <MyObject:123>, ..., <MyObject:125> ]
```

What is the most efficient way to do so ?

I used `[[dico allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]` to key a list of ordered keys but as the keys are NSString they are not ordered the right way (I could end up with [ 42, 46, 5, 56. ...].

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031990/how-to-sort-an-nsarray-using-compareoptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sorting NSStrings that represent numbers you want to use the NSNumericSearch option to sort them like numbers, e.g. 1 < 20 < 100 < 1000. Here's an example:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
    [d setObject:@"C" forKey:@"3"];
    [d setObject:@"A" forKey:@"1"];
    [d setObject:@"B" forKey:@"2"];

    NSArray* sortedKeys = [d keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@",sortedKeys);

    NSArray* sortedObjs = [d objectsForKeys:sortedKeys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
    NSLog(@"%@", sortedObjs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the keysSortedWithCompartor method of your NSDictionary, where you can supply a comparator to compare the keys whatever way you wish (in your case, by comparing them as integers).

Comment: what is the exact signature of this method ? I do not find it in apple documentation.